# Android textview and alert dialog help

Tags: android, runtime, textview

So, I have a list alert dialog where i you pick, lets say a color. When the user picks the color i want to display the color he picked in a textview. The dialog is working fine, but I'm having problems with the textview. I need a way to change the text of the textview during runtime. Any suggestions?

Here's the code

```
 public void a_Turnus(View view){
    setContentView(R.layout.a_turnus);
    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Mat", "Fiz", "Eng"};
    final Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Odaberi");
    alert.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            text.setText(items[item]); 
        }
    });
    text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                 AlertDialog myalert = alert.create();                                     
                                    myalert.show();
                            }
                          });
```

}

Comment: Post some code and the exception from LogCat when it crashes.

Comment: i got it working somehow, now another question. how can i store which item the user chose so the next time the app starts its the way he left it. is there a way to make the textview stay that way until the next time it's changed?

Comment: You'd have to store the user's choice and appropriate TextView data in a Sqlite database or in a file which you can read in when the app starts again.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MyTextView.setText()`, this function update the text immediately

Comment: What is the exception throws?

Comment: there arent any, the dialog and the textview are not in the main content view, it chrashes when i try to change the content view through a button

Comment: Do the "R.id.test" in the "R.layout.a_turnus"